# SQL for count all in last 12 months with PHP

Tags: php, mysql, date, count, timestamp

I have a MySQL/MariaDB database which includes timestamps created with the PHP function `date()`.

Like this:

```
ID | Name | Date
--------------------------
12 | John | 123456789
13 | Mike | 987654321
...
29 | Rick | 123498765
30 | Adam | 987651234
```

Now I need to **get the count of all persons per month based in the last 12 months since the current one**.

Example:

Currently is March, so I need to get something like this:

```
March has 3 persons
February has 14 persons
January has 16 persons
December has 13
November has 16
October has 30
...
```

And goes on.

How can I do this with PHP?

---

So far I have this simple `for` loop which returns last 12 months and then the timestamp for each, but I don't really know how to compare the returned timestamp with the DB timestamp.

```
for ($number = 0; $number <= 11; $number++) {
    $month = strtotime("-".$number." month");

    echo "Timestamp: ".$month."<br>";
    echo "Month: ".date("F", $month);
    echo "<hr>";
};
```

That loop returns something like this:

```
Timestamp: 1488398035
Month: March
---
Timestamp: 1485978835
Month: February
---
Timestamp: 1483300435
Month: January
---
Timestamp: 1480622035
Month: December
---
Timestamp: 1478026435
Month: November
---
Timestamp: 1475348035
Month: October
---
Timestamp: 1472756035
Month: September
---
Timestamp: 1470077635
Month: August
---
Timestamp: 1467399235
Month: July
---
Timestamp: 1464807235
Month: June
---
Timestamp: 1462128835
Month: May
---
Timestamp: 1459536835
Month: April
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this in MySQL, simply sub `table_name` for the actual name of your table:

```
SELECT
    YEAR(FROM_UNIXTIME(`Date`)),
    MONTH(FROM_UNIXTIME(`Date`)),
    count(*) as total
FROM table_name
WHERE `Date` > UNIX_TIMESTAMP(DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 12 month))
GROUP BY YEAR(FROM_UNIXTIME(`Date`)), MONTH(FROM_UNIXTIME(`Date`))
```

Generally this concept is more efficient (especially once you have large amounts of data) if you you use a datetime column instead. This will work though. This query also assumes 12 months ago literally, to the day, you could calculate the exact timestamp of the first day of the month and etc... Again, this would be way easier and more efficient with a datetime column.

Comment: This will (under some conditions) return 13 rows, rather than 12. And the earliest month will have a count for a partial month, not the entire month. It depends on how the specification "last 12 months" is interpreted, but personally. I'd be leery of returning a "partial" count for a previous month.

Comment: Yeah, the only way to get a perfect 12 months is to calculate out the exact unix timestamp of the first day of the month 12 months ago. i am hoping OP moves to use datetime columns as then you could do something as simple as `Date >= '2016-03-01'`

Comment: Thanks. This query just gives me an error: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'count(*) as total FROM my_table_name WHERE fecha` > UNIX_TIMESTAMP(DA' at line 5` - I don't think I can move to datetime columns, I already have +300 rows.

Comment: You are missing a ` before fecha. 300 rows is nothing though, i'll paste query to get a better column:

Comment: ALTER TABLE table_name ADD COLUMN newfecha DATETIME; UPDATE newfecha SET newfecha=FROM_UNIXTIME(fecha);

Comment: I will give a try! - Seems like the ` was not the problem.

Comment: Works for me. You're obviously changing your column names for example vs what you actually use. I'd write the query based on your actual column names if that had been what you used in the question. Good luck man.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `FROM_UNIXTIME` and `DATE_FORMAT` functions to convert timestamp into date and date into string respectively, and get the counts, e.g.:

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(FROM_UNIXTIME(`date`), '%Y-%m') as `month`, COUNT(ID) as count
FROM table
GROUP BY `month`;
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. This query returns only the existent ones, so if I only have data from 3 months ago to now, it will return only 3 rows. I need 12, even if they are empty. Can this be done with SQL?

Comment: If you have data from 3 months ago then you can `subtract` that much duration from start date and query accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

To return twelve rows, one for the current month, and eleven for the preceding months, along with a count (even when the count is zero), we can do something like this:

```
SELECT CONCAT(DATE_FORMAT(r.sd,'%M is ')
             ,COUNT(t.name)
             ,' person'
             ,IF(COUNT(t.name)=1,'','s')
       ) AS `something_like_this`
  FROM ( SELECT d.d - INTERVAL i.i - 0 MONTH AS sd
              , d.d - INTERVAL i.i - 1 MONTH AS ed
           FROM ( SELECT DATE_FORMAT(NOW(),'%Y-%m-01') AS d ) d
          CROSS
           JOIN ( SELECT 0 AS i UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL SELECT 3
                  UNION ALL SELECT 4 UNION ALL SELECT 5 UNION ALL SELECT 6 
                  UNION ALL SELECT 7 UNION ALL SELECT 8 UNION ALL SELECT 9
                  UNION ALL SELECT 10 UNION ALL SELECT 11
                ) i
          ORDER BY sd DESC
       ) r        
 LEFT
 JOIN mytable t
   ON t.date >= UNIX_TIMESTAMP(r.sd)
  AND t.date <  UNIX_TIMESTAMP(r.ed)
GROUP BY r.sd
ORDER BY r.sd DESC
```

The inline view `r` is designed to return 12 rows. On those rows, we return the start and end date of the period. In this case, the first day of the month, and the first day of the following month.

An outer join to the table we want to get a count of rows from. Given that the `date` column is stored as a unix style 32-bit integer (seconds since epoch), we can use the MySQL UNIX_TIMESTAMP function to convert the MySQL `DATE` values (from `r`), so we have values we can compare.

---

To answer the question that was asked, yes, it's also possible to achieve this type of functionality in PHP.

With the current code that generates the "beginning" timestamp for the period, also generate the "ending" timestamp (the first of the following month.)

Then execute a query that gets a count.

```
  SELECT COUNT(t.name) AS cnt
    FROM mytable t
   WHERE t.date >= 1488326400    /* 2017-03-01 00:00 UTC */
     AND t.date <  1491004800    /* 2017-04-01 00:00 UTC */
```

Fetch the result, and output a line. For the previous month, run another query

```
  SELECT COUNT(t.name) cnt
    FROM mytable t
   WHERE t.date >= 1485907200    /* 2017-02-01 00:00 UTC */
     AND t.date <  1488326400    /* 2017-03-01 00:00 UTC */
```

Fetch the result, output a line. And repeat.

Comment: The long query returns 12 of this `4d61726368206973203120706572736f6e`, `46656272756172792069732031303720706572736f6e73`, etc. What is that?

Comment: That looks like HEX representation.  `4d61726368206973203120706572736f6e` interpreted as ASCII (or latin1) is "`March is 1 person`". `46656272756172792069732031303720706572736f6e73` is hex representation of "`February is 107 persons`". Likely, the database driver/ORM is assuming the return from the query is "binary" rather than character, and is choosing to return HEX representation.

Comment: It's not clear whether you are using PDO, MySQLi, or some other database interface library/ORM. We could dispense with the CONCAT function, the DATE_FORMAT function, and return just two columns, the date and the count, and do the formatting in PHP.

Comment: I'm using MySQLi. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT
YEAR(FROM_UNIXTIME(`Date`)),
MONTH(FROM_UNIXTIME(`Date`)),
count(*) as total
FROM table_name
WHERE date(from_unixtime(`Date`)) 
BETWEEN CURDATE() AND CURDATE() + INTERVAL 12 MONTH;
```

Comment: I tried this but just gives me the last month (March).

Comment: I'm trying with PHPMyAdmin but looks like doesn't recognise the "interval" word.